# Immutable NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

On my `viewDidLoad` I load from a webservice the first 5 items of an array and put them on a `NSMutableArray` of mine. Also on this View I have `UITableViewController` that displays the items of my `NSMutableArray` with the contents from the webservice. When I scroll to the last item of the `UITableView` I am loading the 5 next items from the webservice and add them to my `NSMutableArray` and reloading the table data in order to display all the 10 items.

The problem is that when I try to add to my existing `NSMutableArray` the 5 new objects from the webservice the program crashes with the message: `Exception: -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object`

The way I am accessing the `NSMutableArray` in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Any idea on what it could be?

Comment: Can you paste the declaration of your myMutableArray property?

Comment: please show the code of how you initialize the array :-)

Comment: My guess is that you don't have an NSMutableArray, but a plain old NSArray.  Just because the pointer is named "mutable" does not make the object mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, look for warnings in your compiler output. You likely have are assigning an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` variable. This will often generate a warning. Your build should have no warnings in it. This is critical for ObjC code (many things you would think of as "errors" are only warnings in ObjC). If you're ignoring warnings, then you're going to have a lot of problems.

You can have this situation without creating a warning if something is cast to `id`. For example, if you fetch your "`NSMutableArray`" (really an `NSArray`) from an array or dictionary, you won't get a warning about the type mismatch. Look for these situations. Basically, audit each point you assign `myMutableArray` and make sure that you're actually assigning a mutable array.

Comment: I was setting the result of the webservice call directly to the nsmutablearray. Now I allocated and initialized it first and then added the objects one by one, and it worked fine. Thanks a lot! :)